# Crystal Reports passing in string array and using the IN operator

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to be able to pass in a string (or array) like 1,6,33 and so on.  I can easily pass in a string like this. Then within the report in a selection formula have something like:-

```
{fieldname} IN {?myParam}
```

but cannot get this to work, any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: are you using this parameter in SQL?

Comment: Set `{?myParam}` to allow multi-value and it should work with your selection formula.

Comment: agree with MatSnow unless you are using this parameter in a command table

Comment: No not using in SQL, just straight in the report.  I'd tried setting it as a multi-value and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to pass an array. Not a comma separated string.

Comment: Sorry thought I'd sent my reply to this.  Managed to get it working. I'd been looking at it to long and missed the obvious. I had my parameter set as a string, when it should have been a number even though I had Cstr({fieldname}) IN {?myParam}, ended just having to do ({fieldname}) = {?myParam}